# Absolute positioning: why are my boxes offset?

Tags: html, css, web, css-position, absolute

This may seem like a fairly basic question but I'm just looking for some clarity.

context:

I'm in the process of developing a fairly complex website, an idea for display I have had consists of a series of boxes that can be spawned onto the screen. For reasons that are too convoluted to explain here I have decided the best way to organize these boxes is through a parent-child structure within my HTML. This is because setting the value of the child div's position being 100% away (either Top, Left, Right, Bottom) is good way for the boxes to tesselate and not overlap.

Here is my HTML:

```css
.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4 {
    display: flex;
    border: solid black;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid rgb(72, 255, 72);
    border-width: 3px;
}

.box-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid rgb(255, 72, 72);
    border-width: 3px;
}

.box-3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid rgb(218, 255, 56);
    border-width: 3px;
}

.box-4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid rgb(112, 86, 255);
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content "text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-1">
    box1
    <div class="box-2">
      box2
      <div class="box-3">
        box3
        <div class="box-4">
          box4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Does anyone know why each of my boxes is offset in the top value? Has it got something to do with the margins maybe?

Here's an img of what I'm talking about:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtooO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because of `top: 0%`. If you remove that, it will align side by side. The reasoning is because the top property sets the top edge of the element 0% down from the top edge of its parent container. The parent container has a border that is on the outside of itself, which is why it looks like you have a cascading effect. The base of the border is the top edge of the element.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp